# React-Native stuck at Loading dependency graph done. No errors

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have a problem with my app, after running react-native run-android, the procees stop with blank page app at get stuck at loading dependency graph done... nothing happens. Everything was ok and suddenly not work anymore.

I tried everything i found on the internet... still not working. Any ideas?

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s1aW.png)
[This is what i get..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGWrX.png)

Comment: do you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it might be an issue with watchman. Please try to close all  terminals and emulator, clean the project and give the build. It did worked with me when i came across the same situation.

Comment: What do you mean by ' all terminates ' and how to i close them?

Answer (score 0):

When you’re unable to load a bundle, look at the packager logs or the error message displayed in the Expo client to see if it’s related to the packager. If so, you should try clearing the packager’s state to reduce the chance the bug is related to a stale cache or corrupt process.

These instructions are for macOS and Linux, but the general ideas apply to Windows as well.

Stop XDE/exp, which should also stop the packager. Check your list of running processes to ensure these processes are not running.

1. Delete node_modules in your project
2. If your project depends on other local projects (e.g. has a file:
   URI in its dependencies), clear those local project’s node_modules
   directories too for good measure even though it’s probably
   unnecessary.
3. Clear your Yarn or npm cache, depending on which you’re using, with
   yarn cache clean or npm cache clean
4. Run yarn or npm i to install your dependencies again
5. Run watchman watch-del-all to clear Watchman’s state
6. Kill the watchman daemon process
7. Delete the packager’s cache directory with rm -fr $TMPDIR/metro*
8. Start XDE or exp
9. With exp, run exp r -c for good measure

And just to be sure, force quit the Expo client on your phone or simulator and re-open it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me. I had this issue after transferring my data from my old mac to my new one. It turned out that the brew installed python was not properly transferred. So, basically I uninstalled and reinstalled watchman.

```
brew uninstall watchman python
brew install watchman
```

I then restarted the packager, and I was ready to go.